# HowTo compare std::wstring & char*?

Tags: c++, compare, wstring

What I have:

- [wstr1] 1 **std::wstring** value (e.g. "(GMT+04:30) Kabul")
- [str2] 1 **char*** filled with the same data as std::wstring (with the same text)

I'm simply trying to compare this two value - but the following code doesn't appear to work. KMP.

Here is the converter from char* to std::wstring,

```
std::wstring TimeZone::TimeZone::char2ws(const char* src)
{
    /* Convert to a wchar_t*
     * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631(v=vs.80).aspx
     */

    // Convert to a wchar_t*
    size_t origsize = strlen(src) + 1;
    const size_t newsize = 512;
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, origsize, src, _TRUNCATE);

    return wcstring;
}
```

after that I made simple compare with

```
// wstr1 is std::wstring, with "(GMT+04:30) Kabul" string
// wstr2 = char2ws(str2), 
return (wstr1 == wstr2);
```

And no luck. String in VSVC2008 IDE debugger are visually equal.

**Question**: why do compare method gives me *false* always?

Thanks.

---

**Solution**: great thanks to [Alexandre C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373025/alexandre-c)

```
bool weirdEquals(const std::wstring& str, char const* c)
{
    std::string c_str(c);
    if (str.size() < c_str.size())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return std::equal(c_str.begin(), c_str.end(), str.begin());
}
```

PS. I made some changes.

Comment: wcstring[] is a stack variable, how can you return it? Are you missing a final '\0'? Why aren't you checking the error code from mbstowcs_s?

Comment: He returns a std::wstring by value, not a reference to the array.

Comment: @James "Why aren't you checking the error code from mbstowcs_s?" Errno is 0, that means no errors, conversation succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare like this, if you're sure that you have only ASCII characters.
Otherwise, you can pass a custom (locale dependant ?) comparer to `std::equal`.

```
bool weirdEquals(char const* c, size_t n, const std::wstring& str)
{
    if (str.size() < n) return false;
    return std::equal(c, c + n, str.begin());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare strings, you need to compare them via the same character set. `wchar_t` and `char` are clearly using different character sets so you cannot compare them using a typical char-for-char string comparison.

Typically, you would convert the `char*` string to a `wchar_t*` string (using `mbtowcs` or `MultiByteToWideChar`) so you can compare them both as Unicode strings, as you are doing.

But I suspect in your case though, you only ever expect simple ASCII characters to match, in which case you can do a char-by-char comparison, comparing `wchar_t`s to `char`s. Note: do *not* use a cast to do this.

As to why your conversion is not working, see @Erik's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `newsize`, not `origsize`, to mbstowcs_s.

Also, consider using:

```
wchar_t wcstring[newsize] = { 0 };
```

Comment: Thanks, but _You need to pass newsize, not origsize, to mbstowcs_s._ this is a little bit confusing me...  The official MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631(v=vs.80).aspx sad, that in `mbstowcs_s` must be `origsize` value, no? _wchar_t wcstring[newsize] = { 0 };_ - no help